# Parsing a raw email message that may be in html or various strange encodings and converting it to plain text, the way, say, pine might display it

Tags: email, parsing, bots

The reason I want to do this is to make it easy to parse out instructions that are emailed to a bot, the kind of thing majordomo might do to parse commands like subscribing and unsubscribing.  It turns out there are a lot of crazy formats and things to deal with, like quoted text, distinguishing between header and body, etc.

A perl module to do this would be ideal but solutions in any language are welcome.

Answer (score 4):

Python has the [email](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-email.html).

```
>>> import email
>>> p = email.Parser.Parser()
>>> msg = p.parsestr("From: me@example.com\nSubject: Hello\nDear Sir or Madam...")
>>> msg.get("Subject")
Hello
>>> msg.get_payload()
'Dear Sir or Madam...'
```

It supports MIME and pretty much all encodings that are included in Python. HTML will just be text to it, but you can use BeautifulSoup or Tidy+ElementTree to get the text out of it.

Answer (score 2):

Can't say I have every done exactly what you are talking about, but maybe you should give this a read as it sounds like the author is doing what you describe.

[Parsing MIME & HTML](http://mipagina.cantv.net/lem/perl/mime.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could do worse than look at [CPAN](http://cpan.org/) for email-related modules.

One that I've used in the past for breaking out subjects, and bodies has been [Email::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Email::Simple)

Answer (score -1):

Some ideas:  http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=666607

Here's my incomplete solution, which actually works for my purposes (parsing commands emailed to a bot).  I'm keeping it here for reference until there's a definitively better answer.

```
# Take an email as a big string and turn it into a plain ascii equivalent.
# TODO: leave any html tags inside of quotes alone.
sub plainify {
  my($email) = @_;

  # translate quoted-printable or whatever this crap is to plain text.
  $email =~ s/\=0D\=0A/\n/gs;
  $email =~ s/\=0A/\n/gs;
  $email =~ s/\=A0/ /gs;
  $email =~ s/\=2E/\./gs;
  $email =~ s/\=20/\ /gs;
  $email =~ s/\=([\n\r]|\n\r|\r\n)//gs;

  # translate html to plain text (or enough of it to parse commands).
  $email =~ s/\&nbsp\;/ /gs;
  $email =~ s/\<br\>/\n/gis;
  $email =~ s/(\<[^\>]+\>)/\n$1\n/gs;

  return $email
}
```